# How to calculate returns for other frequencies?

Tags: mathematical-economics, finance

Hey am newb started studying economics
I have questions about returns of any asset
I know how to calculate annualized returns by (1+returns)^(1/N)-1=annualized_returns
N=number of periods

Let's say I have hourly data returns
How to calculate weekly returns

Comment: It should be N instead of 1/N.

Comment: Punctuation makes reading easier,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same equation with $N$ being the number of hours in a week, or more generally, the number of shorter periods in a longer period:
$$
(1+r_\text{short})^N=1+r_\text{long}.
$$
You can manipulate this equation to express $r_\text{short}$ or $r_\text{long}$ or even $N$ as needed.